# UIDragInteraction Preview Rotation

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, ios11

I first create an `UIImageView`. Upon creation, this `UIImageView` has no rotation, and I am going to call this state the `Original Rotation`. Then I rotate the `UIImageView`. The image now has a rotation, and I would call this state the `New Rotation`. To finish everything off, I drag the image to a different position in the same view.

I currently have the following delegate functions for dragging:

```
func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession) -> [UIDragItem] {
    let touchedPoint = session.location(in: self.view)
    if let touchedImageView = self.view.hitTest(touchedPoint, with: nil) as? UIImageView {
        let touchedImage = touchedImageView.image

        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: touchedImage!)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = touchedImageView
        return [dragItem]
    }
    return []
}
func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, previewForLifting item: UIDragItem, session: UIDragSession) -> UITargetedDragPreview? {
    return UITargetedDragPreview(view: item.localObject as! UIImageView)
}
func dragInteraction(_ interaction: UIDragInteraction, willAnimateLiftWith animator: UIDragAnimating, session: UIDragSession) {
    session.items.forEach {(dragItem) in
        if let touchedImageView = dragItem.localObject as? UIView {
            touchedImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

When the dragging process initiates, the image that I am dragging lifts off, and the preview shown retains the `New Rotation`. However, as I start moving my finger, and the preview starts moving with it, the preview loses the `New Rotation`, and instead shows the `Original Rotation`. How can I be able to make the preview retain the `New Rotation` when I am dragging it?